# python Indexerror: String index out of range in my Cipher code

Tags: python-3.4

Does anyone have any idea why this error occurs? The error is exactly as it says in the title, indexerror: String index out of range.
My code is:

```
import random

Cipher = input("What would you like to encrypt? ")

alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'] 

a = 0

aValue = True

while aValue == True:
    for letter in Cipher:
        pos = random.randint(0,25)
        letter = alphabet[pos]
        if letter == 'a':
            lol = 0
        else:
            if a >= 24:
                aValue = False
            if Cipher[a] == 'a' or Cipher[a] == 'A': #It says the error occurs on this line
                Cipher = Cipher.replace(Cipher[a], letter)
            a = a + 1

print("Your final message is: " + Cipher + ".")
```

I have only put the 1 letter in as it wont let me put all of my code. I hope you can help me. Thanks,
-space

Comment: Hi, @space482 not entirely related but i would use `import string    a = list(string.ascii_lowercase)` to generate an alphabet list, its faster than hard-coding.

Answer (score 0):

After your for loop completes, the variable *a* will equal the length of *Cipher*.  For instance, if the ciphertext is five characters long, then *a* will equal 5. This happens because *a* is incremented once for each letter in *Cipher*.

Then, if *aValue* has not been set to false, the while loop comes into effect and the for loop is run a second time. The variable *a* is never reset if this happens, and it still holds its previous value.  If *Cipher* is of length 5 and *a* equals five, then *Cipher[a]* will be referencing the sixth letter of *Cipher*.  This letter does not exist, as it is in this case only five letters long.  Here is where the exception is thrown.

To fix this, ensure that *a* is always less than the length of *Cipher* for all iterations of all loops.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it still doesn't work, my new code is:                  while aValue == True:
    for letter in Cipher:
        pos = random.randint(0,25)
        letter = alphabet[pos]
        if letter == 'a':
            lol = 0
        else:
            if a > len(Cipher) - 1:
                aValue = False
            if Cipher[a] == 'a' or Cipher[a] == 'A':
                Cipher = Cipher.replace(Cipher[a], letter)
            a = a + 1                      Thanks for your help